# unsigned char как байтовое число

Tags: c++

На MSDN указано, что в C++ никогда не было типа byte и вместо него следует использовать тип unsigned char. Но при попытке вывести такое значение

```
void func(char b) {
    cout << b;
}

func(20);
```

вижу не совсем то, что нужно

[image: use char as byte]

Есть ли какая-то нормальная человеческая возможность работать с однобайтовыми числами или каждый раз придется преобразовывать в int?

Comment: Все-таки есть byte: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte. А так, работайте с `unsigned char`

Comment: @gil9red, честно скажу - я пытался. Но ругается, что нет такого мембера в std-неймспейсе((
2015 студия

Comment: Используйте последнюю студию, с ключом c++17 или c++latest. На дворе 2018 год, какая 2015 студия?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При печати можно выполнить приведение типа, тогда выведется число вместо символа:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(b) << std::endl;
```

Либо можно использовать функцию `printf`

```
printf("%d",b);
```

Comment: Да в том и проблема, что нужно не при печати. Я блин с выявлением overflow промучился несколько часов, пока по старой дельфийской привычке пытался использовать это значение как индекс массива. Я понимаю, что это от моих слабых знаний языка, но тут прям совсем на ровном месте грабли((

Comment: А в чём тогда проблема? Вы можете оперировать с unsigned char'ами как с обычными числами, в памяти то всё равно хранится число.

Comment: агась, я тоже так думал. Но проблема описана мной выше. При передаче unsigned char в функцию и использовании как индекс массива ловлю stack overflow, а если эту же переменную привожу к int - то всё хорошо. И то ли лыжи не едут, то ли я что-то неправильно делаю

Comment: Приведите пример кода.

Comment: я прошу прощения, начал тестировать на свежую утреннюю голову и вижу, что ноги у проблемы переполнения растут откуда-то из другого места

Comment: нашел откуда, с типом char вообще никак не связано. Благодарю вас за помощь в разбирательстве!